# Subset a matrix using a column from another matrix in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a matrix `X1` with 6 columns. Column 3 in this `X1` matrix contains `RouteNo`. I also have a vector `V1` which is extracted from another matrix. Few values from this vector matches with `RouteNo` in `X1`. The task is to take a subset from matrix `X1` where `RouteNo` from `X1` matches with `RouteNo` from `V1`. `V1` contains extra `RouteNo` than in matrix `X1`.

```
> X1
    V1 V2       V3 V4   V5 V6
1    1  2 84072082  1 2000  0
2    2  2 84046006  1 2000  0
3    3  2 84046006  1 2001  0
4    4  2 84046006  1 2002  0
5    5  2 84021002  1 2002  0
6    6  2 84021002  1 2003  0
7    7  2 84021002  1 2003  0
8    8  2 84021002  1 2004  0
9    9  2 84021002  1 2005  0
10  10  2 84021002  1 2005  0
11  11  2 12468015  1 2006  0
12  12  2 12468015  1 2007  0
13  96  2 12468015  2 2000  0
> V1
 [1] 84021001 84021002 84021105 84046006 84046007 84046008 84046009 84046011 84046013 84046014
> n2 = subset(X1, subset = X1[,3] %in% V1)
> dim(n2)
[1] 0 6
```

I tried using `subset` function but I am not getting the desired result. I expect to get the matrix as below

```
2    2  2 84046006  1 2000  0
3    3  2 84046006  1 2001  0
4    4  2 84046006  1 2002  0
5    5  2 84021002  1 2002  0
6    6  2 84021002  1 2003  0
7    7  2 84021002  1 2003  0
8    8  2 84021002  1 2004  0
9    9  2 84021002  1 2005  0
```

Is there any other way to get the result? Any help is appreciated. Thank in advance.

Comment: Joshua Ulrich, How do you format the R code on StackOverflow site ?

Comment: Indent four spaces or uses the curly braces button, you can press edit on your post and see for yourself

Comment: NB_R you don't want to use the same name for a vector that you use as a column name in your matrix. Give your names useful names.

Comment: As a pointer, note that when you said "matrix", it appears that what you really meant was "data frame". In R, these are two different types of objects. Although they behave in similar ways (and are meant to), getting them confused can often lead to errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running into problems with scoping. You have a column named `V1` in your data.frame `x1`. Change your look up vector to a name that isn't a column name and everything should be fine, i.e.:

```
subset(x1, V3 %in% v1)
```

or use `[` to index directly

```
x1[x1$V3 %in% V1,]
```

The proof is in the pudding:

```
txt1 <- "    V1 V2       V3 V4   V5 V6
1    1  2 84072082  1 2000  0
2    2  2 84046006  1 2000  0
3    3  2 84046006  1 2001  0
4    4  2 84046006  1 2002  0
5    5  2 84021002  1 2002  0
6    6  2 84021002  1 2003  0
7    7  2 84021002  1 2003  0
8    8  2 84021002  1 2004  0
9    9  2 84021002  1 2005  0
10  10  2 84021002  1 2005  0
11  11  2 12468015  1 2006  0
12  12  2 12468015  1 2007  0
13  96  2 12468015  2 2000  0"
txt2 <- "84021001 84021002 84021105 84046006 84046007 84046008 84046009 84046011 84046013 84046014"

x1 <- read.table(textConnection(txt1))
#Note the lowercase
v1 <- read.table(textConnection(txt2))
#Make "V1" as you have it
V1 <- v1 

> #Bad
> dim(subset(x1, V3 %in% V1))
[1] 0 6
> #Good
> dim(subset(x1, V3 %in% v1))
[1] 9 6
#Does subset method equal the direct indexing method
> all.equal(subset(x1, V3 %in% v1),x1[x1$V3 %in% V1,])
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @ulvund - been there, done that, have several hours of head scratching to prove it :)